# Accessing std array element passed as non-type template parameter gives a non compile-time constant value on msvc

Tags: c++, templates, c++20

I'm trying to pass a `static constexpr std::array` as a non-type template parameter. However accessing an array element gives a non compile-time constant value on msvc compiler.

MSVC (16.4.5, 16.5) fails to compile the sample, but clang (9, 10) and gcc (9.1, 9.2, 9.3) compile fine.

What is the correct behaviour according to the current standards (>=c++20)? Is this a MSVC compiler bug?

Here is the sample https://godbolt.org/z/7YsnAF

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T, size_t N, const std::array<T, N> & arr, typename Fn, size_t Index = 0>
void iterate_static_array(Fn && fn) {
    static constexpr T e = arr[Index];
    fn.template operator()<e>();
    if constexpr (Index + 1 < N) {
        iterate_static_array<T, N, arr, Fn, Index + 1>(std::forward<Fn>(fn));
    }
}

int main() {
    static constexpr std::array<int, 10> values = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
    iterate_static_array<int, 10, values>([]<int e>() {
        std::cout << "compile-time e = " << e << "\n";
    });
}
```

Comment: It's not really a "bug" when [Microsoft's own conformance docs state that they haven't implemented that feature yet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/overview/visual-cpp-language-conformance?view=vs-2019). It is simply "to be done". Bugs are for when you claim to support something but don't do it correctly.

Comment: Do you know which PR corresponds to this feature?

Comment: What is a "PR"?

Comment: The document number. Or the entry in the table mentioned above, so I could track the feature.

Comment: Perhaps the document linked by @NicolBolas has changed since he posted the comment but I don't see any reference to the unimplemented feature.  [This bug report](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/C:-Cannot-index-array-passed-as-templa/946250) raised around the same time notes even a C-style array passed as a template parameter fails under MSVC and a `std::array` in this context can give an internal compiler error which definitely doesn't feel like an unimplemented feature.

Answer (score 2):

I would say it is a bug.

The only C++20 feature you are using is the template syntax for lambdas, which according to [Microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/overview/visual-cpp-language-conformance?view=vs-2019) should already be supported since VS 2019 16.2.

If you remove that and test e.g. the following program:

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T, size_t N, const std::array<T, N> & arr, typename Fn, size_t Index = 0>
void iterate_static_array(Fn && fn) {
    static constexpr T e = arr[Index];
    fn.operator()();
    if constexpr (Index + 1 < N) {
        iterate_static_array<T, N, arr, Fn, Index + 1>(std::forward<Fn>(fn));
    }
}

int main() {
    static constexpr std::array<int, 10> values = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
    iterate_static_array<int, 10, values>([]() {
    });
}
```

then there is no C++20 feature left and since C++17 this should compile, because you are allowed to pass a reference to an object with static storage duration as template argument and its usage as `arr[Index]` is also a constant expression, as the reference was initialized with a constant expression and the referenced object is also constant initialized.

Yet MSVC still gives the same error message, whether in c++2a or c++17 mode. Both GCC and Clang compile this in C++17 mode.

Comment: I used lambda template just to enforce `e` to be very very compile time constant. It's irrelevant to the question.